# What is the difference between mouseenter and mousehover?

Tags: c#

In a C# Windows application there are 2 different mouse events, `MouseEnter` and `MouseHover`, which are both triggered when the cursor is over the object.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: I think mouse hover is when the mouse spends a little time over the target, think tooltips

Comment: This is a *very* googlable question.

Comment: These are __strange__ vote counts on both the worthless question and the answers!

Comment: @TaW I'm guessing the ["hat effect"](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/).  Timing is everything.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you are in Windows Forms:

Mouse Enter occurs:

> Occurs when the mouse pointer enters the control.

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Mouse Hover:

> Occurs when the mouse pointer rests on the control.
>
> A typical use of MouseHover is to display a tool tip when the mouse
>   pauses on a control within a specified area around the control (the
>   "hover rectangle"). The pause required for this event to be raised is
>   specified in milliseconds by the MouseHoverTime property.

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

To set MouseHoverTime globally (**not recommended**, see @IronMan84's link [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81d13e2f-72cf-40f8-9bc0-d6f2ddc37955/how-can-i-change-mousehovertime-property) for a better solution), you can use the `SystemParametersInfo` function. Because thats a Win32 API call, you'll need PInvoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);
```

Called as:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI.SPI_SETMOUSEHOVERTIME, 
                     desiredHoverTimeInMs, 
                     null, 
                     SPIF.SPIF_SENDCHANGE );
```

Sigantures from PInvoke.NET: [SystemParametersInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.systemparametersinfo), [SPIF (Enum)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SPIF.html), [SPI (Enum)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/SPI.html)

I didn't include the `Enum` signatures here because they are so freaking long. Just use the ones on PInvoke.Net (linked above)

For complete information on the SystemParametersInfo API call and its parameters, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: and how to set the MouseHoverTime property ?

Comment: @IbrahimHero There are several ways. IronMan's link is what I found as well. It also seems that you can change a registry key to set it system wide. In general, you should avoid changing this value. Googling "Set MouseHoverTime" gives the relevant pages.

Comment: I know Iam being stupid and all but IronMan's link wasnt very useful to me...could you gaive a direct example about how to set it ?

Comment: @IbrahimHero Done. Since you didn't like the other link, I posted a sample for the global API call.

Answer (score 11):

[MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) is when your mouse just goes into the area.

[MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is when your mouse stays there for a bit (typically used for tooltips).

As far as mouse events go, the `MouseEnter` event occurs before any others. Also, you can manually set how long the mouse must hover over the area before the `MouseHover` event gets fired. You can see more about that [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81d13e2f-72cf-40f8-9bc0-d6f2ddc37955/how-can-i-change-mousehovertime-property).

EDIT: I changed the link on adjusting MouseHoverTime. It turns that you can't easily do it, and that it is highly recommended not to, since it's a system value, which will affect all applications on the machine. Instead, the new link shows how to use a new, application-specific variable to do it manually.

Comment: Just so you know, I borrowed your link as the "correct" way to set `MouseHoverTime` since the OP insists on a different approach. I would use your way :)